# copy cell range and paste below

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet names "Queue Tracker" and in that a tab named "Compiled Dispositions". I would like to auto select and copy the multiple ranges (which all  contain formulas) and paste it to "n" number of rows below. Where n can be 100 or 1000 or even 3000.

The ranges to select and copy are : B3:K3, M3:V3, X3:AG3, AI3:AR3, AT3:BC3, BE3:BO3, BQ3:BZ3, CB3:CH3, CK3:CP3, CS3:CX3, DA3:DF3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't tag Google sheet questions with Excel or VBA

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's possible to access multiple range selections with Google Apps Script.  So using active selections won't work.  But this treats your selected ranges as one range in which I null out the unwanted columns.  So hopefully you are not planning on copying this into areas that are already populated with dated.  I haven't tested it but you can use it as a starting point.  This will give a chance to get to know our script editor and debugger.

```
function copyYourRowToRange(row, numrows)
{
  var leaveBlank=['0','11','22','33','44','55','67','78','86','87','94','95','102','103'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sht.getRange('B3:DF3');
  var rngA=rng.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<leaveBlank;i++)
  {
    rngA[0][leaveBlank[i]]='';
  }
  var str='B' + row + ':DF' + Number(row + numrows);
  var destR=sht.getRange(str);
  var destA=destR.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<destA.length;i++)
  {
    destA[i]=rngA[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi When I attempt to test the code I get an error on this line "var destR=sht.getRange(str);" the error message reads "Range not found (line 13, file "Code"). Please help

Comment: what parameters did you give it?